# git log How to hide commit message

Tags: git

I'm using code like this:

```
git log --name-only --oneline
```

And it's showing me this [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRh2O.png)

[image]

How to show everything of this except commit message?

Comment: omg, sorry. Second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the commit hash and the files changed use this command:

```
git log --pretty=format:%h --name-only
```

per the documentation for `git log` https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log

You can adjust the format of the log with the `--pretty` option and specifying the format.  All the options available are listed in the documenation.

This version formats the log message to only show the abbreviated sha.  Adding the `--name-only` adds the files changed.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks. I though formatting will show only reference. I mean, show only %h preference

Comment: Um, how to make it in one lane? --name-only making new line

Comment: You are going to have to do some other processing of the log using |.  I am not seeing a way to do that with git log.  Though the commits are separated by new lines so it should be possible.